# Function definition in Macros in C

Tags: c, macros

This code throws out an error saying that "code undelcared."

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAIN() c##o##d##e
int main()
{
    MAIN();
    printf("C program");
    return 0;
}
int code()
{
    printf("C is life");
}
```

Whereas, this code runs smoothly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAIN() m##a##i##n
int main()
{
    MAIN();
    printf("C program");
    return 0;
}
int code()
{
    printf("C is life");
}
```

Output:

```
C program
```

This code also runs smoothly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define macro(n, a, i, m) m##a##i##n
#define MAIN macro(n, a, i, m)

int MAIN()
{
    printf("C is life");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C is life
```

In the first code, why doesn't the code work as like main? I don't know what is the process after the concatenation 'main' is completed by the macro. Kindly explain the process behind these codes, in simple terms.  Thanks in advance.

I also tried by defining the code function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAIN() c##o##d##e
int code(void);
int main()
{
    MAIN();
    printf("C program");
    return 0;
}
int code(void)
{
    printf("C is life\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C program
```

So, defining a function should not be the problem.  My question is, what happens after concatenation?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Obviously_ it should be `#define MAIN(m,a,i,n) int m##a##i##n(); m##a##i##n()` and `MAIN(c,o,d,e);`.

Comment: I have edited the question now, clearly, as per my needed clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C (since the C99 standard) you need to declare all functions before you use them.

In the first example you haven't declared the `code` function before you attempt to use it. You solve it by adding a *function prototype*:

```
// Declare the function, also known as a function prototype
void code(void);

int main(void)
{
    // ...
}

// Define the function
void code(void)
{
    // ...
}
```

The second example works because you use `main` which is already declared at that point. If a function haven't been declared before, the definition also declares the function.

Also note that your macro after expansion doesn't actually *call* the `code` (or the `main`) function. This is good, since calling `main` recursively (directly or indirectly) is generally bad.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you have to define the prototype of your function `int code ()` before any calls :

```
int code (void);
```

The function `main` is declared in assembly code, this is why your second version compiles et runs correctly.

If you want to avoid this error please add `-Wmissing-prototypes` compilation flag in order to let the compiler checks for you if your function has a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `code()` function is not yet declared when `main()` is compiled.

Either move `code()` before `main()`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAIN() c##o##d##e
int code()
{
    printf("C is life");
}
int main()
{
    MAIN();
    printf("C program");
    return 0;
}
```

Or forward declare `code()`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAIN() c##o##d##e

int code();

int main()
{
    MAIN();
    printf("C program");
    return 0;
}
int code()
{
    printf("C is life");
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain that `MAIN()` expands to `code`, not to `code()`, so does not actually call the function `code()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember `macros` are replaced at `preprocessor` stage itself. In `C`, every function needs to be prototyped before using/calling it so that compiler knows in advance about it's `arguments` and `return type` to avoid conflicts.

**Case 1 :-** when below code blocks executes, macro name `MAIN()` got replaced with `code`.

```
#define MAIN() c##o##d##e
int main(){
        MAIN();
        printf("C program");
        return 0;
}
int code(){
        printf("C is life");
}
```

And it looks like below after **pre-processor** stage

```
int main(){
 code; /* errorenous statement */
 printf("C program");
 return 0;
}
int code(){
 printf("C is life");
}
```

observe the line `code;` in above code block, it cause the **compilation error**. When you run above code like `gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror test.c` where it will convert `warning` into `error`.

> error: ‘code’ undeclared (first use in this function)  #define MAIN()
>   c##o##d##e
>                   ^

to solve this, declare the `code()` like before `#define`

```
int code(void); /* declaration */
```

There is one more warning converted into error

> error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]  #define MAIN()
>   c##o##d##e

Because after macro replacement it looks like `code;` and here compiler rightly complaining above *statement with no effect*. So to avoid this 
change the macro name from `MAIN()` to `MAIN`. for e.g

```
#define MAIN c##o##d##e
```

Correct version of case-1 code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int code(void);
#define MAIN c##o##d##e
int main(void){
        MAIN();
        printf("C program");
        return 0;
}
int code(void){
        printf("C is life");
        return 0;
}
```

And it produces output as

```
C is lifeC program
```

**Case 2 :-**  when below code executes, macro name `MAIN()` gets replaced with `main`

```
#define MAIN() m##a##i##n
int main(){
    MAIN();
    printf("C program");
    return 0;
}
int code(){
    printf("C is life");
}
```

And it looks like at preprocessor stage

```
int main(){
    main; /* it causes error */
    printf("C program");
    return 0;
}
int code(){
    printf("C is life");
}
```

**Case 3 :-**  when below code blocks executes, macro name `MAIN()` got replaced with `code` & here you declared the `code()` also.

```
#define MAIN() c##o##d##e
int code(void);
int main() {
    MAIN();
    printf("C program");
    return 0;
}
int code(void) {
    printf("C is life\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And it looks like below after pre-processor stage

```
int code(void);
int main() {
 code;/* error causing statement */
 printf("C program");
 return 0;
}
int code(void) {
 printf("C is life\n");
 return 0;
}
```

Suggest you to compile any C code with

```
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Werror test.c
```

so by converting warning to error you will learn more.

Comment: `MAIN()` in the first case is replaced with `code`, not `code()`.   In the second case it is replaced with `main`, not `main()`.

Comment: @Peter I modified my answer for more clarification to OP problem. Kindly have a look.